# Java - Distributed JPA Lock For Reservation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, concurrency

I am working on a legacy system that allows reservation scheduling. The application is stateless REST and designed to be horizontally scaled. The database, however, is shared between all instances. Before I get a lecture on design and scale, it's not mine - have to make the best of a bad situation (or codebase). Recently we have seen an issue where there are duplicate reservations. I believe it is because of the nature of request response threads. The process currently is, receive request, check database for conflicting time reservation, if none, insert. Depending on time between reads and insert it's possible that both get inserted. Scenario seems to look like this:

```
|------|-------|-------|
R1     C1      I1     RSP

-|--------|-------|---------|
R2       C2     I2   RSP
```

Where R = Request, C = DB Check, I = Insert.

So I believe I could use the @Synchronized annotation which would force all threads to be ordered. The problem comes with the fact that there are multiple instances running so that wont work overall instances. Pessimistic or Optimistic reads and writes dont seem to apply since we are trying to do a read and write combo unless I completely misunderstand. Any thoughts to handle this problem across scale? Would prefer to handle it in java via a table lock or something similar rather then add additional services (kafka, redis, etc).

**EDIT**: the database looks something like this and using h2 in dev and mysql in production.

```
 id |  start_time  | locationid | postingid | userid | duration
```

Comment: What does the conflict check look like? What database are you using?

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE time == ?", Databases are H2 and MySQL

Comment: That does suggest that you could simply add a unique index on `time`. You'd have to handle the exceptions raised in response to duplicate inserts.

Comment: I would need to do it on a series of compound fields. Sorry, I am using mostly sudo code. I dont believe unique index is an option here. It had been considered.

Comment: Can you add more details around the constraints to your question? A database constraint is possible, and is probably the best option.

Comment: I added some DB details. I suppose I could make a unique constraint of start_time, locationid, and userid which would basically mean the user can't have more than one reservation a given location with the same start. The problem is the duration. If the start times are slightly different (say 5 min) and the duration (say 35 min) causes overlap (reservation = start_time+duration). Honestly what I think would work is lock table, check conflict, insert, release lock but I cant seem to find anything that says that is feasible.

Comment: @user3170736 why do your system support user to make two reservation in the same location and start time?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn The location is a table. It supports one user per time. These are the system requirements and this comment is not helpful.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 We are using innoDB and JPA with the Transactional annotation. Row-level locking isnt sufficient here since we arent worried about row data collision. We are worried about two rows of data overlapping.

Comment: What about replacing check then insert, by insert, commit, check then keep or delete ? (The commit being necessary to insure serial visibility).

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Implementing something like this from scratch is no rocket science but maybe you may want to take a look at this GitHub project: https://github.com/alturkovic/distributed-lock

I'm neither involved in this project nor currently using it but it looks very promising. You simply need to create a Spring configuration with `EnableJdbcDistributedLock`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcDistributedLock
public class LockConfiguration {
}
```

And create the needed database table:

```sql
create table lock (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  lock_key varchar(255) unique,
  token varchar(255),
  expireAt timestamp,
);
```

Once this is in place you can sychronize method calls in a distributed environment by a simple annotation (taken from the project's examples):

```java
@JdbcLocked(expression = "#name")
public String sayHello(final String name) {
  return "Hello " + name + "!";
}
```

Comment: The database should be doing this work, not the application.

Comment: @JonathanR, the OP is asking for a distributed JPA based locking mechansim and that's exactly what my answer provided. Maybe it's not possible for the OP to execute all involved calls in a DB transaction?

Answer (score 1):

The database should be handling this. You can either:

- use locking reads. `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will prevent any rows you're reading (e.g. in your `COUNT(*)` query) from being written to. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html
- change the database's isolation level. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

You can test your changes locally with a command-line SQL client: open two concurrent transactions, and try different ways of interleaving the `SELECT` and the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logical thing would be to lock the location. If I understand the domain correctly you are reserving a specific location (such as a room) for a time slot given by start time and duration? In that case you probably have an entity for location already. If not you can perhaps create one and add a matching table. The code would then be simple:

1. Get a pessimistic lock on the location from the request with JPA
2. Check the database for conflicts
3. Insert the new reservation
4. Commit

A table lock will really hurt scalability, but locking a specific location should work.